# FATAL EXCEPTION; Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an application which which uses swipe views. I used the template provided by android studio to create the swipe views. The template provided by android studio provides 3 fragments to swipe between which are working fine, I can swipe back and fourth between these no problem.

The problem I am having is creating a 4th fragment. I have created the Java file, the XML and have updated my `MainActivity` to account for the 4th tab. The 4th tab is showing in the menu and I can swipe to the 4th tab. But, when I try to swipe back to any of the other tabs from the 4th tab the app crashes.

The error I am getting in the Android Monitor is:

```
12-07 14:08:11.951 2586-2586/com.example.application.placepicker 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.application.placepicker, PID: 2586

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file 
line #11: Error inflating class fragment

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error 
inflating class fragment

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #11: 
Duplicate id 0x7f0d00a1, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another 
fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment

at 

android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView
(FragmentManager.java:3447)

at 
android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView
(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)

at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView
(LayoutInflater.java:189)

at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)

at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)

at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)

at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)

at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)

at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)

at com.example.application.placepicker.Tab2.onCreateView(Tab2.java:29)

at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)

at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState
(FragmentManager.java:1299)

at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState
(FragmentManager.java:1528)

at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps
(BackStackRecord.java:753)

at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps
(FragmentManager.java:2363)

at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether
(FragmentManager.java:2149)

at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps
(FragmentManager.java:2103)

at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction
(FragmentManager.java:1984)

at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss
(BackStackRecord.java:626)

at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate
(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)

at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1268)

at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal
(ViewPager.java:668)

at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal
(ViewPager.java:630)

at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:611)

at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
$ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.onTabSelected(TabLayout.java:2191)

at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.dispatchTabSelected
(TabLayout.java:1164)

at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1157)

at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1127)

at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1426)

at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.performClick
(TabLayout.java:1536)

at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)

at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit
$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

My MainActivity is:

```
public class TabbedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabbed);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tabbed, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();
                return tab3;
            case 3:
                Tab4 tab4 = new Tab4();
                return tab4;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Places";
            case 1:
                return "Street View";
            case 2:
                return "Steps";
            case 3:
                return "Weather";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

My Tab4.java is:

```
public class Tab4 extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab4, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
}
```

Anything else you need to know to find a solution please let me know

Thanks

Edit:
This is the XML file of tab4

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.application.placepicker.TabbedActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Weather Fragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the XML of Tab1 which is working fine:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.application.placepicker.TabbedActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_places"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:text="Launch place picker"
    android:width="350dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/section_label" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPlace"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#3F51B5"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewUserEmail"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: IT is indicating an error in your xml file of the the 4th fragment. Check xml file of the 4th fragment, Make sure the the names of the views and  viewgroups are proper.

Comment: I have uploaded the XML file to the question above. I cannot see where the problem is, the `tab4.xml` file is similar to the rest of my XML files.

Comment: Isn't your switch() missing the breaks for each different case?... Both your switches...

Comment: I don't think so because everything was working fine up until I added the 4th Tab and the switch was exactly like that

Comment: Can you please show the full stacktrace?

Comment: @cricket_007 I have now posted the full stack trace in the above question

Comment: Did you actually read the error? `Duplicate id 0x7f0d00a1, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another 
fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment`... Your question has no references to a Google maps Fragment... Please show a [mcve] of the actual code in the error

Comment: Also read `at com.example.application.placepicker.Tab2.onCreateView`, so not clear why you're focusing on Tab4... ViewPagers will load both Fragments on the side... Tab4 will recycle Tab2. When you go back to Tab3, Tab2 is reloaded and crashes

Comment: I assumed as the other fragments were working without tab4, that tab4 is causing the problem. In tab2 I am using a fragment to load a google map, is this causing the crash?